# Grails bootstrap sometimes won't save

Tags: mysql, grails, spring-security, bootstrapping

Have you ever experienced that the Bootstrap doesn't save (with flush or without flush - same result) anything in the db?

I'm using the Spring security core plugin, and I'm creating roles and user in the init-method.

My app starts up fine, without errors, but I have nothing in my db...

I have made some changes, I'm running a MySQL-database and might have made some wierd changes that enable this behaviour.

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain that your objects pass validation?

I always use

```
object.save(failOnError: true)
```

for objects I create in `BootStrap.groovy`. `save` will throw an exception if validation fails.
An alternative would be to check that your call to `save` returns true.

Comment: I've tried a try-catch(Exception) while doing a .validate() - NOTHING! I didn't do a detailed analysis since it was late last night and I just didn't have the power...I'll neeed to verify that save really returns true...thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I spent few aggravated hours with same problem after which I realized that I had set

```
dbCreate = "create-drop"
```

Make sure you have

```
dbCreate = "update"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I might have "out configured" myself!